# Where are the system spellchecking dictionaries?

Tags: macos, dictionary, spelling

I would like to use the spellchecking dictionaries bundled with OS X from the command line (`hunspell`), but can't seem to find them. In `/System/Library/Spelling` there are only 2 files `pl_PL.{aff,dic}`, and `find / -name '*.dic'` revealed nothing.

I know I can dowload dictionaries from OpenOffice etc., but I'd like to find the ones bundled with OS X.

**EDIT** To clarify, there are at least two kinds of dictionaries in OS X:

- Definitions used in Dictionary.app. I'm not interested in those.
- Word lists used by the system spellchecker (red dotted lines). I know OS X uses hunspell because [the hunspell website](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) says so, and there are numerous posts on how to add new ones ([1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/easy-way-to-install-additional-spell-check-dictionaries-for-os-x), [2](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/SpellingDictionaries)). Just, I don't want to add new ones but use the English one that obviously comes with the system.

Comment: What build of hunspell is in play? (as it's not explicitly included as a command line tool on OS X - adding that detail might help you get a better quality answer.) [Another answer here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21429/uk-spelling-dictionary-teach-os-x-all-ize-spellings) shows that the spell check routines for TextEdit source words from the same place as Dictionary app - so be clear to explain how your problem is different than locating /Library/Dictionary or ~/Library/Dictionary

Comment: @bmike libhunspell is in /usr/lib/libhunspell-1.2.0.0.0.dylib. I'm not sure which of the answers you're referring to, the top-rated answer copied words from Wikipedia? Another answer + comments in this thread however is correct and exactly what I'm after (http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/21446/54379)

Comment: Now that you have added information to your question it makes more sense so my answer was wrong and I removed it.

Comment: /usr/share/dict there is a words file in there

Comment: @thipani, libhunspell is a library and not callable directly from the command line, what is hunspell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spelling dictionaries you are interested in appear to be located in the following location (checked on 10.8.4 and 10.6.8):

```
/System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/Resources/
```

The word lists are stored in this directory by language, so U.S. English is in the `English.lproj` folder.

However, these files are stored in a binary format that I haven't deciphered yet...

Answer (score 1):

Under macOS Catalina...

There are two locations:

- `/System/Library/Services/AppleSpell.service/Contents/Resources/AppleSpell.8`
- `/Users/${HOME}/Library/Dictionaries/`

The first is the system spell check dictionary and the second is the user dictionary that is created/modified when the user adds a learned word. The second one can be edited using any standard text editor.