# Writing emails in different languages in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app

How can I write emails in another language, with a spell check for that language?  Is there a language dictionary to opt for?

Answer (score 3):

If "Automatic by Language" does not give adequate results, you can set the dictionary to a specific language in Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I do it all the time and yes the spell check is set to automatically detect.

There are few settings you have to do in syst preferences -keyboard like this.

[image: spell]

If you need a different keyboard layout (characters) then set it up again in system preferences by adding that language so you can easy switch by clicking on the icon in the menu bar.

[image: leng]

Not all language spelling are installed by default, so if yours is not a part of:

[image: spelling]

you can add it following this instructions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11842/46541