# Install external dictionaries to use with Word for Mac's Spelling and Grammar

Tags: catalina, ms-office, dictionary

I am trying to use Spelling and Grammar in Word for Mac with a language that is not supported by default (Slovenian).

[The standard way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11827/375227) to do this for other applications is to put the dictionary files (.dic and .aff that I downloaded from LibreOffice Extensions) to `Library/Spelling`. Word, however, seems to *disregard these system-wide settings*.

I also tried to put these files under `Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/` and import the .dic file [as Custom dictionary of '(none)' language](https://cl.ly/c4c6e8d18c2c). In this way, when setting the language to English (UK) and specifying the Custom dictionary added above, some words are recognized correctly . However, most of the words are still incorrectly marked as containing spelling mistakes and suggestions do not reflect the full dictionary.

Is there any other way of importing external dictionaries?

I am using Word for Mac v16.36.

Comment: Word does not use Mac spellcheck.  I don't know of any way to add things to its "proofing tools".  They have a forum at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac

Comment: Word for Windows seems to have what you want.   https://www.microsoft.com/sl-SI/download/details.aspx?id=52668